# How can I use a S3 bucket of a different AWS account in DMS of my account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration, aws-dms

I know the credentials (access key and secret) of a S3 bucket of a different AWS account. Now I want to create an Database Migration task with this s3 bucket of the other account as source endpoint. Has anybody an idea what steps I need to do to use this S3 bucket for a migration task?

Regards Gerrit

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the credentials of the other account.  You need two (2) things for a resource in one account to use a bucket in an external account.

1. You need to make sure the DMS service access role you specify in the source endpoint has the S3 IAM permissions to read from that bucket.  Take a look at [Prerequisites When Using Amazon S3 as a Source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html)
2. You need to make sure the bucket in the external account allow other accounts to access it.  This is accomplished with a [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).